# Salesforce Formula field Syntax Error

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field, salesforce-id, cloud

**Throws Error "Syntax Error."**

Object :- Opportunity Line Item

Field1 :- UnitPrice Currency(16, 2)

Field2 :- Cost_Price__c Currency(16, 2)

Field3 :- Discount Percent(3, 2)

Field4 :- Gross_Profit__c Formula (Currency) 2 decimal Places

**Formula want to Implement is  :- UnitPrice - Cost_Price__c – (unit price * discount)**

Please Help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, but did you actually *try* so far?

Comment: i had tried to convert value(discount) so that it converts in to Number.
as well as i tried to change the Formula's return type as "number" with 2 decimal places. But same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you put a space where one didn't belong:

```
UnitPrice - Cost_Price__c – (UnitPrice * Discount)
```